# jquery ajax url depending on button press

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have a form with 3 buttons, and I want the post to be handled by AJAX. Each button should trigger a different query string at the end of my ajax request url.

For example when the user clicks

```
doRegPwd ?config=reg_password_save
doRegGen ?config=reg_password_generate
doRegDisable ?config=reg_disable
```

How can I do this with jquery?

```
$('[name="reg_password"]').submit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: 'framework/AJAX/config_actions.php?config=reg_password_generator',
        data: $(this).serialize(),
        success: function(data){
            alert(data);                    
        }
    });
});
$('#doRegPwdGen, #doRegPwd, #doRegDisable').click(function(e){
    $(this).closest('form').submit();
});
```

html:

```
   <form name="reg_password" method="post" action="">
      <label>Password for <a href="external_forms/register.php<?php if(!empty($row_config['reg_password'])) { echo '?reg_pwd=' . $row_config['reg_password']; } ?>" target="_blank">registration form</a></label>
      <input name="reg_password" type="text" id="reg_password" class="input" value="<?php echo $row_config['reg_password']; ?>">
      <br>
      <input name="doRegPwd" type="button" id="doRegPwd" value="Save" class="btn btn-success">
      <input name="doRegPwdGen" type="button" id="doRegPwdGen" value="Generate" class="btn btn-space btn-info"></button>
      <input name="doRegDisable" type="button" id="doRegDisable" value="Disable" class="btn btn-space btn-warning">
    </form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### jQuery

- `$('[name^="doReg"]')` matches your inputs as each name attribute begins with "doReg"
- `e.preventDefault()` was substituted for `onsubmit="return false"` (in HTML)

---

```
$('[name^="doReg"]').click(function(e) {

    var query = $(this).data("query");
    $(this).closest('form').submit();

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: 'framework/AJAX/config_actions.php?' + query,
        data: $(this).serialize(),
        success: function(data){
            alert(data);                    
        }
   });

});
```

### HTML

- We are now storing data using data attribute, an HTML5 feature.
- As we're using HTML5, why not use semantic `<button>`s too

---

```
 <form name="reg_password" onsubmit="return false" method="post" action="">   
    <button name="doRegPwd" data-query="config=reg_password_save"></button>
    <button name="doRegPwdGen" data-query="config=reg_password_generate"></button>
    <button name="doRegDisable" data-query="config=reg_disable"></button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

A couple of points:

1. If you have ids or classes you can use use them not name in the
   selector.  Should be faster
2. Why use `input type="button"`instead of a `<button>`element.
3. Submit event is for forms.  With buttons just bind to the click event.

I would actually do a single click event and set the URL as a data element. In your example two trigger form asubmit but you say you want each to their own URL so I'll do that. Form elements don't need a name.  I have changed to an id and set the click event as a delegated event there so I only need to have one event. Something like.

HTML:

```
<form id="reg_password" method="post" action="">
<!-- other inputs here -->
      <br>
      <button name="doRegPwd" data-mynamespace-url="reg_password_save" type="button" id="doRegPwd" class="btn btn-success">Save</button>
      <button name="doRegPwdGen" data-mynamespace-url="reg_password_generate" type="button" id="doRegPwdGen" class="btn btn-space btn-info">Generate</button>
      <button name="doRegDisable" data-mynamespace-url="reg_disable" type="button" id="doRegDisable" class="btn btn-space btn-warning">Disable</button>
    </form>
```

Javascript:

```
$(function(){
   $('#reg_password').on('click', '.btn', function(){
       var form = $(this).closest('form');
       $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: 'framework/AJAX/config_actions.php?config=' + $(this).data('mynamespace-url'),
        data: form.serialize(),
        success: function(data){
            alert(data);                    
       }
    });
   });
});
```